# How can I disable MobileSafari's content scaling on orientation change?

Tags: iphone, html, css, orientation, mobile-safari

I'm making a mobile version of my application support site and I have a little WebKit/iOS/HTML/CSS problem here...

I have a page, `index.php`, with `mobile.css` file attached. In my `<head>` tag I have:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, max-scale=1.0" />
```

My `body`'s css:

```css
body {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../../images/textured_bg.png) repeat;
    color:#454545;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0 1px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Everything works fine in portrait orientation, but when I rotate my iPhone to landscape, Safari scales my content so it looks like in portrait, but a little bigger:

[image]

My question: Is there a way, without [making custom css for each orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519998/scale-down-mobile-safari-viewport-width-when-ipad-is-in-portrait-orientation/6521273#6521273), to force Safari not to scale my content?

Comment: I don't have an iphone myself, but is this normal behaviour for the phone?  Would a user be expecting the content to be scaled upon switching the orientation?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't want my content to be scaled, because my images get pixelated. PS: There are some sites that don't scale their content, e.g. StackOverflow: http://cl.ly/0o0t2N2225063T2N2E05

Comment: If pixelated images is the issue, you could consider using svg instead.

Comment: It is not the matter of pixelating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will probably want to use the `<meta name="viewport" .../>` tag (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mobile/viewport_meta_tag) and [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)). The mobile Stack Exchange layout uses this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0" />
```

Comment: MDN says use commas, Apple says semicolons. Seems like both can use semicolons, though.

Answer (score 10):

The key part to fixing this isn't the meta viewport tag (though that's important, too, but for different reasons). Here's the magic that fixes the text size on orientation change.

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

(I got this from StackExchange's mobile CSS file.)

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Disabling user scaling is not very user friendly. For more info see http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/

Comment: This doesn't work if a text input is focused while `onorientationchange` fires. See a [demo here](https://idorecall.com/static/bug-demos/mobile-safari-content-scaling-on-rotation-in-input/).

Answer (score -1):

I tried commas, didn't work - then tried semicolons, that DID work. iPod touch, iOS 4.2